# Plotting $α^2\sin^2 θ-\sin^2(αθ)=0$, where $α≠0$ is an arbitrary complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Let $$α^2 \sin^2 θ-\sin^2 (αθ)=0,$$
where $α≠0$, and $α=a+ib$, $θ∈(0,2π]$.

I want to draw a graph between $\mathrm{Re}\,α$ and $θ$ and a graph between $\mathrm{Im}\,α$ and $θ$. The real part of $α$ is between the interval $(0, 3)$.

Any help or hint to write the Matlab program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to type math on this site.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha produces an interesting plot for this, but I'm not sure what I'm looking at: https://goo.gl/bah1AA Note that depending on the value of $\alpha$, there may be no solutions or multiple solutions in $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that:
$$\sin(a+ib)=\sin a\cosh b+i\cos a\sinh b$$
So that:
$$\sin^2(a+ib)=\sin^2 a\cosh^2 b - \cos^2 a\sinh^2 b +\frac{i}{2}\sin (2a)\sinh (2b)$$
And:
$$\alpha^2\sin^2\theta−\sin^2(\alpha\theta)=$$
$$(a^2-b^2+2abi)\sin^2\theta−\sin^2(\alpha\theta)=$$
$$(a^2-b^2+2abi)\sin^2\theta−\sin^2 (a\theta)\cosh^2 (b\theta) + \cos^2 (a\theta)\sinh^2 (\theta b) -\frac{i}{2}\sin (2a\theta)\sinh (2b\theta)=0$$
You want to plot $a$ or $b$ vs. $\theta$. to that end, compare the real and imaginary parts to get:
$$2ab\sin^2\theta=\frac{1}{2}\sin (2a\theta)\sinh (2b\theta)$$
$$(a^2-b^2)\sin^2\theta−\sin^2 (a\theta)\cosh^2 (b\theta) + \cos^2 (a\theta)\sinh^2 (\theta b)=0$$

These two equations are rather intractable, so really the only thing you can do is loop over $\theta$, and for each value solve these two equations for $a,b$ numerically. The fact that there is more than one solution per $\theta$ makes this a very tough problem, as numerical solvers that use gradient descent like methods will only converge to one of the many possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks @nbubis for the reply and guidance. I have use the above guidance and separate the real and imaginary parts. The real and imaginary parts again contain  the numbers a, b. is it possible to draw the graph of the real part, we can take the imaginary value 'b=0'? because in the values of \alpha, 'b' is the imaginary part and the vice versa for the graph of imaginary part.

Comment: Real part: 
(a2- b2) 〖sin〗^2 θ-〖sin〗^2 aθ〖cosh〗^2 bθ+〖cos〗^2 aθ〖sinh〗^2 bθ=0
Imaginary part: 
2ab〖sin〗^2 θ-1/2  sin⁡(2aθ)  sinh⁡(2bθ)=0

Comment: @YasirNadeem - See update.